# Return a group where one of it's items is equal to a value

Tags: c#, linq

Currently, this code will search through all the groups, and return a CameraItem where the uniqueID is equal to something.

What I want happening is I want the code to return the CameraItem's group (CameraGroup).

The code that returns CameraItem:

```
public static async Task<CameraItem> GetItemAsync(string uniqueId)
{
    await _sampleDataSource.GetSampleDataAsync();
    // Simple linear search is acceptable for small data sets
    var matches = _sampleDataSource.Groups.SelectMany(group => group.Items).Where((item) => item.Id.Equals(uniqueId));
    if (matches.Count() == 1) return matches.First();
    return null;
}
```

My attempt at returning CameraGroup:

```
public static async Task<CameraGroup> GetItemGroupAsync(string uniqueId)
{
    await _sampleDataSource.GetSampleDataAsync();
    // Simple linear search is acceptable for small data sets
    var matches = _sampleDataSource.Groups.SelectMany(group => group.Items).Where((item) => item.Id.Equals(uniqueId));
    if (matches.Count() == 1)
    {
        // Something here?
        // Would it be a modification of var matches?
    }

    return null;
}
```

What will i need to modify to return the CameraItem's CameraGroup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, `matches` will contain all groups which have at least one item matching `uniqueId`:

```
static async Task<CameraGroup> GetItemGroupAsync(string uniqueId)
{
    await _sampleDataSource.GetSampleDataAsync();

    var matches = _sampleDataSource.Groups
        .Where(group => group.Items.Any(item => item.Id.Equals(uniqueId)));

    return matches.Count() == 1 ? matches.First() : null;
}
```

You might consider using `FirstOrDefault()` or `SingleOrDefault()` like so instead of the `Count() == 1` check -- makes it a little cleaner I think:

```
static async Task<CameraGroup> GetItemGroupAsync(string uniqueId)
{
    await _sampleDataSource.GetSampleDataAsync();

    return _sampleDataSource.Groups
        .SingleOrDefault(group =>
                        group.Items.Any(item => item.Id.Equals(uniqueId)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, but I needed to replace Items.Any with Items.FirstorDefault - is there a reason for Items.Any?

Comment: @ForeverLearning: That is a bit strange if you are using the code as above. `Any` returns true if the predicate (ie the lambda) is true for any item. The key being it returns a boolean which is what `Where` is after. `FirstOrDefault` on the other hand returns an instance of the item, presumably a `CameraItem`. This shouldn't be acceptable in the where unless you are then compariing it to your know item. In this case you may have a problem if the group doesn't have that item as its first item.

Comment: Sorry, correction, I meant Groups.Where. I changed that to FirstOrDefault as I got an explicit conversion error

Comment: Ah, we had the same frame of thought then. Good!